# How to use methods of a module in another class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a module called mymodule.
The module has a method `sayHello()`

So this works:

```
import mymodule
print(mymodule.sayHello())
```

Now I want to use the methods (all of them) from `mymodule` for a class.

```
import mymodule

class Grandma(object):

    def __init__(self):
        ##import methods from mymodule.
```

So I can do in another class:

```
from grandma import Grandma
self.Grandma.sayHello()
```

How can I achieve this in python?

atm I can only achieve this by using an extra attribute which I don't want

Comment: Why would you want to?  Anyone who can access the `Grandma` class can also access `mymodule` and call the functions there directly.

Comment: What is the `self` in `self.Grandma.sayHello()`?

Comment: I suspect it has to be: `from mymodule import Grandma`, as the Grandma class is defined in mymodule.py. Afterwards you can just do: `grandma = Grandma()` and then `grandma.sayHello()`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is relatively bad design, and recommend you find a different way of expressing what you want to do.

That said, using the [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) method of a parent class makes this pretty easy: we just loop though the directory of the module and assign all the attributes to identical attributes on the class.

```
from abc import ABC

class ModuleABC(ABC):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, module, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for name in dir(module):
            # Ignore attributes we define as part of the class and "private" attributes
            if not hasattr(cls, name) and not name.startswith('_'):
                setattr(cls, name, getattr(module, name))

import math

class Grandma(ModuleABC, module=math):
    pass

print(Grandma.tau)
# 6.283185307179586
```

This doesn't actually require that `module` be a module either: it should work on just about any target.

Answer (score -1):

You can literally import stuff right inside the class definition:

```
class Something:
    from stuff import a, b

    def __init__(self):
        self.a()
```

You may want to take a look at how this can be used in a real-world project [here](https://github.com/ForceBru/PyVM/blob/master/VM/__init__.py). I'm not saying this is the best method (I actually find it relatively ugly), but it works fine.